# jquery dataTable doesnot work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with datatable to get table values. but i am not able to get any data, even table length. Not sure what I'm missing. Please someone help me on this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  var data = table.rows().data();
  alert("2");
  alert('The table has ' + data.length + ' records');
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've fixed the snippet. If you check the console you'll see this error: `Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined`. If you Google that you'll probably be able to find an anaswer

Comment: in my actual code,  i have properly given <thead><tbody>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```js
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 var data = table.rows().data();

  alert('The table has ' + data.length + ' records');
  $('td').click( function() {
    
    console.log(this);
    
    row_index = table.fnGetPosition(this)[0];
    
    console.log(row_index);
    
  });
```

```css
body {
 font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #fff;
}


div.container {
 min-width: 980px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$4,525</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$4,525</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Russell Chavez</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$3,750</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$5,000</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$4,965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$4,200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$3,600</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$6,730</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$2,875</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$4,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$5,300</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$4,080</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$3,120</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working. could u mention what plugin i have to use

Answer (score 0):

Data table is not an inbuilt property of JQuery. You have to use external plugins for it? Have you included them?
link https://datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

Datable needs thead and tbody to work properly (you mention that it is in your code but not in your snippet) You also need minimum css. Your problem seems to be the version you use. Update to the lastr one (see snippet)

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
 var data = table.rows().data();
/*  alert("2");*/
  alert('The table has ' + data.length + ' records');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```